MacBook Pro M1 screen replacment black
I had broken my MacBook Pro M1 (A2338) screen some time ago. Now finally I got around to replacing it. Got a "suposedly" working screen from a doner machine. Once I replaced it the new screen just went black no picture (I could here the chime). Further more I could not even connect external screen -- no image what so ever (and no power going through usb c cable).
So my question is: is it 100% sure that the replacement screen is faulty or could I have messed up something with installation (returning the old broken screen restores the connection to an extrenal monitor and the old screen has picture in its half (unbroken) screen as it did before?
Would a broken screen aslo somehow prevent a signal to go to the exteral screen ? (charger seems to work with 0 problems with the new screen).
Thanks.
photo attached

What was the nature of the original damage? Without pictures, we will be guessing perhaps so much as to be unhelpful.

it fell down and broke. added a photo.

Excellent. That makes it slightly more likely you can get a screen repair. If you’re sure no screen drawing is happening (backlight off is different than no image at all on screed) then it’s going to be hard to do much other than re-attache everything and examine every connector for damaged pins….

thanks. so, the new screen is completly off looks exactly the same as when non attached. I gather the pins would be on the connection from the screen, right. But would a faulty pin also cause no external montitor signal coming through ?

I’ve seen a shorted pin on Intel Macs bring down the low voltage differential signal chip to block any output. I don’t have much repair experience with Apple silicon but imaging the circuitry is equally fragile and linked. If the Mac boots with no display attached, maybe test that with an external before reattaching it?
